# Can't plot results of matlab 2D fast fourier transform

Tags: matlab, fft

I conducted a 2D fourier transform on a 4436413x3 matrix using the matlab fft2 command (this one: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html). The product is a 4436413x3 matrix containing complex values. When I try to plot the data, I end up with a graph that is all one color or an error message that references the complex values in my data.

I have tried interpolating to create a 2D set of values using the griddata() function, however, when applied to my 3D dataset, this returns a 1D vector equal to the z-column in my original 3D dataset. My 3D dataset consists of x, y, and z points, and in my attempt to interpolate I used vq = griddata(x,y,z,x,y). I had also tried to create a 4436412x3 meshgrid for my query points (using [xq, yq] = meshgrid(4436412, 3), and then using xq and yq as my query points), but this was returning NaN.

When I run
Y = fft2(x);
imagesc(abs(fftshift(Y)))
I get a single purple box.

When I run
Y = fft2(x);
imagesc(Y)
I get the following error message:

```
Error using image
Complex values are not supported. Specify the color data as numeric or logical values.

Error in imagesc (line 52)
    hh = image(varargin{:}, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
```

Comment: 4 million times 3? That is an extreme aspect ratio for an image. You should not display that as an image, but rather plot the 3 columns as line plots. Are you sure you want to do a 2D FFT, and not 3 1D FFTs?

Comment: So, the error is quite clear, and it makes sense, a complex value is essentially 2 values, so you can't plot it as an image, because each pixel can only have 1 value.

Comment: @AnderBiguri how can I then go about transforming the values into ones that aren't complex?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I was asked to perform a 2Dfft on the dataset. I know it's huge-- it's a high resolution white light scan of a surface. I'm also confused about how to perform a 2D transform on a 3D dataset-- I haven't thought about fourier transforms in a very long time.

Comment: Are you sure the 3 isn’t the RGB dimension, and the 4M isn’t really 2000x2000 or something like that? You probably want to do 2D FFTs over the two spatial dimensions, one for each color channel.

Comment: Hummmm… 4436413 is a prime number. I’m guessing someone is pulling your leg. None of this makes sense. Why would a scanner produce an array with a prime number of samples?

Comment: @CrisLuengo There shouldn't be an RGB dimension because there's no color data for the scan. We're trying to quantify the roughness of the surface, so the scan only records the distance from the surface to the scanner in the z-dimension at each x and y coordinate. The dataset originally had 9006000 observations, however there was no height data for many of them and thus they were omitted (leaving me with 4436413 observations). No one is "pulling my leg"-- I'm doing this as a final project for a class.

Comment: Oh, so one of your columns is x, the other is y, and the third is z? That makes a lot more sense. Don’t treat this as a 2D array, it is a point cloud. Applying the FFT to it makes no sense. If you want to use the FFT, you will need to interpolate to create a 2D array of z values, sampled at a regular x-y grid. You cal also try a 2D non-uniform FFT (nuFFT), not sure how well those work.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you so much for the help. Can you either tell me how to do this type of interpolation, or point me towards a resource that can teach me how to do this? I've never done anything like this before.

Comment: Use this function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, but it doesn't seem like this solves my problem. I'm still getting a graph thats all just one color.

Comment: This question doesn’t have any answers yet, so you can update it with what you’ve done so far. Saying “it didn’t work” without showing what “it” is, does not allow me to help.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry for being abstract. I've updated the question-- still struggling to map my 3D dataset to a 2D one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply the FFT, you need data to be sampled on a regular grid. Your data represents (x,y,z) coordinates of points. Here's how to use `griddata` to resample these coordinates onto a regular (x,y) grid:

```matlab
% Generate example data, let's say x and y are in the range [-3,3]:
n = 62500;
x = rand(n, 1) * 6 - 3;
y = rand(n, 1) * 6 - 3;
z = sin(4*x) + cos(2*y); % an example function
data = [x,y,z]; % This is a 4436413x3 array with (x,y,z) coordinates

% Interpolate z values onto a regular (x,y) grid:
[xq, yq] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x), max(x), sqrt(n)), ...
                    linspace(min(y), max(y), sqrt(n)));
zq = griddata(x, y, z, xq, yq);

% griddata doesn't extrapolate, writes NaN instead. Let's fill those
% in with zeros (maybe a different value is more meaningful in your
% application).
zq(isnan(zq)) = 0;

% Now you can apply a 2D Fourier transform:
Z = fft2(zq);
imshow(log(abs(fftshift(Z))), []);
```

Comment: I did this using [xq, yq] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x), max(x), 2), ...
                    linspace(min(y), max(y), 4436413)), producing a 4436413x2 zq. I think this is what I wanted, given that I want a 2D dataset? Is there a reason I should interpolate onto a square grid?

Comment: @bluekangaroo Why would you sample the x axis only twice, and they y axis 4 million times? You don’t need a square grid, but you need a sensical grid. Start with `scatter3(x,y,z)` and look at your data. How are points sampled? Now decide on a grid that makes sense when you look at that. Decide how you want to split up each axis. Then build that grid with `meshgrid`.